# documentation - is it a template?

Tags: java, hibernate, documentation, prettyfaces

I see that many sites are using the same template of documentation:

[PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/docs/prettyfaces/snapshot/en-US/html/GettingStarted.html)
[Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/tutorial.html)

and more.

Is it a template that I can download somewhere? It's so clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both OCPSoft (the author of PrettyFaces) and Hibernate use DocBook for publishing the documentation. The entire site is (re)generated using Maven, via the [Maven jDocBook plugin](http://www.jboss.org/maven-jdocbook-plugin/). The styles (which can include CSS styles, fonts and images) applied to the documentation are custom-made, but atleast the one for Hibernate appears to be available in the [SVN repository](http://www.hibernate.org/sourcecode.html).

**NB**: You'll probably need to check the license before you can use the files in your projects.

Comment: You can thank JBoss.org for creating these lovely templates. OCPSoft based our template on the Seam Framework templates. Styles and examples for usage can be found in the PrettyFaces pom.xml build files. 

http://code.google.com/p/prettyfaces/source/browse/prettyfaces/trunk/docs/pom.xml?spec=svn371&r=332

Comment: @Lincoln, thanks for the link. I believe the files for prettyfaces are distributed under LGPL, would I be right?

Comment: Hi!I don't understand how to I download and install this plugin?

Comment: @Odelya, the plugin can be used directly in a Maven project, by appropriate configuration of the POM. Maven will automatically download the plugin and utilize it when the required goals are to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Its DocBook, I believe.